# A modified secretary problem where time is of essence

Tags: probability, applications

The famed [secretary problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) asks when you should decide to hire, given that you cannot postpone the decision, and that you can objectively rank the candidates. [I've seen](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2Fj.jmp.2005.11.003) that the solution for getting the best **expected value** candidate is to stop after $\sqrt{N}$ candidates, for a given $N$ total candidates.

I'm wondering if there are any closed solutions for the following modification:

1. There are an infinite amount of secretaries, but the rate they apply is constant, say $f$.
2. Time has value - so that one is willing to compromise in exchange for less time without a secretary. That is, one is interested in maximizing the expected value of $X_t - g(t)$, where $g(t)$ is some increasing function of time.

I feel this problem is a more realistic model of the real world problem, but I haven’t seen a solution for it. Any ideas?

Comment: In the original problem, it is $\frac Ne$, not $\sqrt N$, then pick the first that is better than any so far.

Comment: @RossMillikan - I'm talking about the modification I referenced - one is interested in maximizing the expected value of the candidate, not the probability of getting the best one.

Comment: If you're going to talk about expected values, you need to specify the distribution your secretaries are sampled from.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury - Bearden assumed a uniform distribution, but I'd be glad to see a solution for either a uniform or Gaussian distribution.

Comment: So you want to select the $t$th candidate such as to maximize the expected value of $X_t - \alpha t$, where $\alpha$ is the value of wasted time? Also, I notice that if you treat time as a constraint instead, in that you must hire a secretary within time $T$ (which is also a good model of some real-world situations), this is the usual secretary problem with $N=fT$.

Comment: @RahulNarain - good point about the constraint, but I'm interested in the case $X_t -\alpha t$, or even better $X_t - g(t)$.

Comment: If you take a uniform distribution and a constraint of the form $X_t - \alpha t$, then you must also hire a secretary in bounded time.  I think it's more common to model things like this with exponential depreciation, though, although that might not be the most relevant factor in the case of hiring an actual secretary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of problem is known as "optimal stopping," and there's an entire theory of optimal stopping with lots of textbooks and courses available.  Some of the variants you've described above are analyzed here, for instance:

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Stopping/sr6.pdf